# Best Practices: How to check for a constant in an array using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm not really sure how to do this. I have an object and I want to set a 'type' property on it, but before doing that I want to check to make sure it's a valid type.

I was thinking this is a good time to use constants since the type names won't change (nor do I want them to be).

```
// this is just a sample of what I was thinking:
class Foobar
{
    const TYPE_1 = 'type 1';
    protected $_types = array(
        self::TYPE_1
    );

    public function setType($value)
    {
        // check to make sure value is a valid type
        // I'm thinking it should be able to accept
        // Foobar::TYPE_1, 'TYPE_1', or 'type 1'
        // for flexibility sake. But I don't know
    }
}

$foobar = new Foobar();
$foobar->setType('TYPE_1'); //what should go here? (best practice)
```

**Update:** I decided I didn't really need to use constants in the first place, but I've accepted an answer that I think could have gotten the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array with all types `$_types`, then you can directly check if value presents in it:

```
class Foobar
{
    const TYPE_1 = 'type 1';
    ## declare all available types as static variable
    ## don't forget to change it when new type will be added
    protected static $_types = array(
        self::TYPE_1
    );
    public function setType($value) {
         if (in_array($value, self::$_types)) {
              // type is valid, we can use it
         }
         else {
              // type is wrong, reporting error
              throw new Exception("wrong type [".$value."]");
         }
    }
}
```

But it require additional work to support this array to make sure that all posible types are in array. Also it should be `static`. So the only copy of data will be used for all instances.

Answer (score 2):

To get the available constants in a class, you're going to have to use [Reflection](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

For example:

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass( $this );
$constants = $ref->getConstants();

// Constants now contains an associative array with the keys being
// the constant name, and the value the constant value.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would print the array. You would see the string values. So you can just check if  $value is in $_values.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. The actual code is a bit of code I pulled from a production app, but you get the idea.

```
<?php
class Example {
    protected $SEARCH_TYPES = array('keyword', 'title', 'subject');

    function getSearchType($val) {
        if (in_array($val, $this->SEARCH_TYPES)) {
            return $val;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Then, obviously, you use this method to validate your input and save it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` would help you, but note that `in_array` has to scan all the array to find the value. So it may be something like:

```
class Foobar
{
const TYPE_1 = 'type 1';
protected $_types = array(
    self::TYPE_1 => true
);

public function setType($value)
{
    $value = strtolower($value); // case-insensitive
    if(isset($this->_types[$value])     // check "type 1"
        || isset($this->_types[str_replace($value, '_', ' ')]))     // check "type_1"
    {
        // OK!
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Invalid type: $value");
    }

}
}
```

If you also want to check Foobar::TYPE_1, use [constant($value)](http://php.net/constant) - it allows checking class constants. Or if you want exact class name use reflection like:

```
list($class, $const) = explode('::', $value);
$refclass = new ReflectionClass($this);
if(get_class($this) == $class && $refclass->getConstant($value)) {
// OK!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't set an array as value to a class variable!

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

> The value must be a constant
>   expression, **not** a
>   variable, a property, a result of a
>   mathematical operation, or a function
>   call.

You could reach the the functionality by using a setter and getter method for your variable but not for a constant.

Comment: the page you mentioned, talks about class constants, not clas members.